How do I join a list of chars using a separator?
I am basically looking for the Haskell equivalent of the following python code:
' '.join(['_','a','b','1'])

I understand that python treats those as strings instead of chars, but... I digress.
MRE:
[if <some condition is true> then '#' else chr elem | elem <- lst] -- lst is [Integer] (appropriate Integer -> Int conversion function applied, but not specified here)

expected output:
['#',' ','a',' ','b',... you get the idea]

What I currently have:
['#','a','b',...]

Best I could achieve was:
concat [if <some condition is true> then "# " else [chr elem] ++ " " | elem <- lst]

which seems like overkill. Is there an easier way to achieve this?
PS: unwords does not take Chars.

The intersperse function will insert a single Char between every pair of characters in a String (or more generally, a single element of type a between every pair of elements in a list [a]). For example:
> intersperse ' ' ['a','b','c']
"a b c"
> intersperse ' ' "abc"
"a b c"

You can also convert a list of characters into a list of single-character strings by mapping the function singleton over the list, like so:
> map singleton ['a','b','c']
["a","b","c"]

which would allow you to apply unwords, or use intercalate to insert a multi-character string between the characters, as in:
> intercalate ", " $ map singleton ['a','b','c']
"a, b, c"



PS: unwords :: [String] -> String [Hackage] does not take Chars.

You are right, it doesn't. But that is not that much of a problem: we can just convert the characters to strings with one character, we can use pure :: Applicative f => a -> f a [Hackage] for this, for example, or singleton :: a -> [a] [Hackage], so:
unwords (map pure ['_', 'a', 'b', '1'])
If you want to work with an arbitrary separator, you can use the intersperse :: a -> [a] -> [a] function in K. A. Buhr's answer.
